# How to disable CSRF in Django 1.7?

Tags: android, python, django, django-views, django-csrf

I am struggling to find a way to disable CSRF for a login view I am trying to implement. What's the best way to do it with Django 1.7? I am developing an Android application that is connecting to the /login url and sending a username and password, I have provided the code for the view below. I have tried to use @csrf_exempt on both the view and the url (in urls.py), but it doesn't work. The error I am getting is "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted".

I have also tried to remove the middleware (django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware), but it doesn't work either.

This is the code for the login view:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def login(request):

    fb_user_id = request.POST.get('username','')
    name = request.POST.get('name','')
    request.session['fb_user_id'] = fb_user_id
    create_user(fb_user_id, name)
    res = {}
    res["success"] = "yes"
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(res))
```

Further, this is the url in urls.py:

```
url(r"^login/$", csrf_exempt(views.login), name='login'),
```

This is the response I am getting:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is how you do it, as I have told you before. If you don't think that is working, you should probably post the full error message.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am getting a full HTML page that starts with CSRF Verification Failed and tells me how to user CSRF properly, but the point is I don't want to use it.

Comment: That looks right to me, so I suspect something else is going wrong. By the way, I suspect you'll need to use `ensure_csrf_cookie()` on that view so that subsequent calls work correctly.

Comment: Kevin, but if I am trying to disable it, why would I ensure the cookie?

Comment: Well since you've disabled it, you should not be getting that page. Which tells me that either you've put the decorator on the wrong view, or the server is not picking up the change, or something else utterly bizarre is happening; but since you refuse to post the actual error message I can't guess what.

Comment: Daniel, it's a Forbidden 403. I am just getting an html page as a response.

Comment: It seems the server is not picking up the change because everything is in place.

Comment: Argh. **What is the content of the error page**?

Comment: I have just updated my question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, do you see anything I might have missed? Thanks.

Comment: any luck?? I also hit the same issue.